# write html in javascript without documet.write

Tags: javascript, html

```
    <script >

    for(i=0;i<=9;i++)
    {

</script>

    <input type="button"  value="1"/>

<script type="text/javascript">     

    }

</script>
```

**This puts button only 1 time if I use document.write it prints 10 times why ?**

Comment: Because the button was placed inside a loop.

Comment: Check console for errors... And start with the basics of `JavaScript`!

Comment: i want to add button 10 times if i will put tag like this in php it will add button 10 times but in javascript i need to put document.write want to know why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript does not behave in the same way PHP does. Whatever you place between the `<script>` tags is a script in and of itself.

So you have two **separate** scripts:
This:

```
for(i=0;i<=9;i++)
{
```

and this one:

```
}
```

Imagine what would happen if you placed these two scripts into two separate files? That's right, both would fail because of syntax errors. If you take a look at the console you'll see what errors I'm talking about.

If you want to print 10 buttons do something like this:

```
<div id="mainDiv">

</div>

<script>
    var mainDiv = document.getElementById('mainDiv');
    for(var i=0; i<10; i++){
       mainDiv.innerHtml += "<input type='button' value='1'>";
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

These script tags are separate scripts. You can use functions or variables defined in the first one, but you cannot have a for loop spanning both.

The html in between is not in the script either. It looks like your trying to use `script` tags as if they're `<?php?>` ones.

Alternatives to `document.write`, is setting the contents of an element's innerHTML or adding an element to the DOM:

```
for(i=1;i<10;i++){
  var btn = document.createElement("button");    
  document.body.appendChild(btn);
}
```

Comment: i want to add button 10 times if i will put tag like this in php it will add button 10 times but in javascript i need to put document.write want to know why

Comment: Yes, I figured you were confusing it with php.
There is no _why_, javascript just doesn't work that way.
The best solution is add it to the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

HTML is not a template engine as PHP so you can't separate a code block into multiple script tags. Each code block must be placed entirely in a `<script></script>` tag pair.

If your purpose is generate 10 buttons with Javascript, please go with `document.write` option

Comment: Do you have any other restrictions with this option?

Comment: Of course there are many other options, but in this context, I assume that he just want to know how 2 options work :)

Answer (score 0):

you are looking for some sort of server side templating. remember javascript runs on the client.